# Age of a Renewal Process as a Markov Chain

Tags: probability, probability-theory, stochastic-processes, markov-chains

I've been working through *Stochastic Processes* by Sheldon Ross and am stuck on example 4.3(c) in the book. The example is as follows

> **Age of a Renewal Process** Initially an item is put into use, and when it fails it is replaced at the beginning of the next time period by a new item. Suppose that the lives of the items are independent and each will fail in its *i*th period of use with probability $P_{i}, i \geq 1$, where the distribution {$P_{i}$} is aperiodic and $\sum_{i}iP_{i}<\infty$. Let $X_{n}$ denote the age of the item in use at time $n$ - That is, the number of periods (including the *n*th) that it has been in use. Then if we let
> $$
> \lambda(i)=\frac{P_{i}}{\sum_{j=1}^{\infty}P_{j}}
> $$
> be the probability that an *i* unit old item fails, then {$X_{n},n\geq 0$} is a Markov chain with transition probabilities given by
> $$
> P_{i,1}=\lambda(i)=1-P_{i,i+1},\quad i\geq 1
> $$
> Hence the limiting probabilities are such that
> $$
> \pi_{1}=\sum_{i}\pi_{i}\lambda(i) \\
> \pi_{i+1}=\pi_{i}(1-\lambda(i)), \quad i\geq1
> $$
> Iterating yields
> $$
> \begin{equation} \label{1}
> \begin{split}
> \pi_{i+1} & =\pi_{i}(1-\lambda(i)) \\
> & =\pi_{i-1}(1-\lambda(i-1))(1-\lambda(i)) \\
> & =\pi_{1}(1-\lambda(1))(1-\lambda(2))\dots (1-\lambda(i)) \\
> & =\pi_{1}\sum_{j=i+1}^{\infty}P_{j} \\
> & =\pi_{1}P\{X\geq i+1\}
> \end{split}
> \end{equation}
> $$
> where $X$ is the life of an item. Using $\sum_{i=1}^{\infty}\pi_{i}=1$ yields
> $$
> 1=\pi_{1}\sum_{i=1}^{\infty}P\{X\geq i\}
> $$
> or
> $$
> \pi_{1}=1/E[X]
> $$
> and
> $$
> \pi_{i}=P\{X\geq i\}/E[X]
> $$

It seems like basic probability but I get to the part where he's iterating to get the expression for $\pi_{i+1}$ and am completely lost. I get that $1-\lambda(i)=P\{X\neq i\}$ and $P\{X\geq i+1\}=P\{X\neq 1,X\neq 2, \dots, X\neq i\}$. So isn't he claiming that $P\{X\neq 1,X\neq 2, \dots, X\neq i\}=P\{X\neq 1\}P\{X\neq 2\}\dots P\{X\neq i\}$ but surely that's not true?

Thanks

Comment: have you tried writing it out in matrix form, i.e. as $P :=\left(\begin{matrix}
1-p_1 & p_1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & \dots\\
1-p_2 & 0 & p_2& 0 & 0 & 0 & \dots\\
1-p_3 & 0 & 0 & p_3 & 0 & 0 & \dots\\
1-p_4 & 0 & 0 & 0 & p_4 & 0 & \dots\\
1-p_5 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & p_5 & \dots\\
\vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \ddots\end{matrix}\right)$

Comment: Well you get the limiting probabilities from $\pi= \pi P$ where $P$ is the transition matrix. $(1-\lambda(1))(1-\lambda(2))\dots(1-\lambda(i))$ would be $p_{1}p_{2}\dots p_{i}$ in your notation. Am I missing something?

Comment: it depends on what you're stuck on which largely depends on your background knowledge.  If it were me I'd suggest verifying that $\mathbf z:=   \begin{bmatrix}
1\\ 
p_1  \\ 
p_1p_2\\ 
p_1p_2p_3\\  \vdots \\ 
\end{bmatrix}$ is a left steady state vector, i.e. $\mathbf z^T P = \mathbf z^T$.  Then you need the normalization (i.e. so it sums to 1) but of course you use the identity $E[X]= 1 + p_1 + p_1p_2 + p_1p_2p_3 + ... = \sum_{k=0}^\infty Pr\{X\gt k\} $.

Comment: I'm stuck on the line $(1-\lambda(1))(1-\lambda(2))\dots (1-\lambda(i))=\sum_{j=i+1}^{\infty}P_{j}$. Everything before and after makes perfect sense. What is that identity for $E[X]$ that you use? Is $p_{1}p_{2}=P\{X>2\}$? I get that $p_{1}=P\{X\neq 1\}$ and $p_{2}=P\{X\neq 2\}$ and that $P\{X\neq 1,X\neq 2\}=P\{X>2\}$ but how is $P\{X\neq 1,X\neq 2\}=P\{X\neq 1\}P\{X\neq 2\}$? Those two events aren't independent, are they? That's pretty much what's confusing me.

Comment: *"What is that identity for [] that you use?"*  The identity which you should know is:   $E[X]=  \sum_{k=0}^\infty Pr\{X\gt k\}$.  *" Is 12={>2}"* Well yes but I can't figure out why you are asking this... look at the matrix $P$. Given a start at state 1, if the return time is $\gt 2$ then that means at iteration 1 you advanced to state 2 (i.e. with probability $p_1$) and then at the next iteration you advanced to state 3 (i.e. with probability $p_2$)-- use markov property: the probabilities multiply.  Drawing a picture / tree may help you.  I don't see why you are stuck here.